# Artistic Calendar layouts with pictures?

Tags: calendar

I am looking for references to layouts of calendars. I am not sure yet which kind of calendar I want to have, the picture may be a background picture or a side picture or anything like that. I have pictures which I want to use to the calendar to make it more than just white or a single colour. I found some layouts [here](http://www.vel.co.nz/vel.co.nz/LaTeX_Templates.html) but more references needed. Google fails with the search like `"related:http://idisk.me.com/velnz/Public/site/LaTeX/"`.

Please, add the label `"reference-request"`. I am looking for material such as books or proper websites that would explain and teach how to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 3):

Try http://teatimeandlayout.wordpress.com/tag/calendar/